# retrieve rows by date: cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

In the data there is one column *timestamp* with pattern:

`YEAR-MM-DD hour:minute:second`

I want to retrieve rows where this timestamp column date e.g. is > 2015-07-01

I dont want to compare time, just date.
I tried:

`SELECT * FROM table_name where timestamp >= '2015-10-01'  limit 10;`

But does not give desired output.

Comment: what is timestamp? your first clustering key? use allow filtering in that case.

Comment: I replaced as '2015-10-01 00:00:00+0200', also did allow filtering, but gives error: _PRIMARY KEY part timestamp cannot be restricted (preceding part first_column is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)_

Comment: timestamp is just example name of third column in table. Before this, there are other 2 columns.

Comment: Please give us your schema for table_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem here, is that Cassandra requires an EQ condition (`IN` also works, but I don't recommend that) on the 1st partition key before allowing any other types of conditions (<, >, etc).  Other solutions like using ALLOW FILTERING or an index may "work," but they will not perform at scale, and also will not return the rows in any kind of order.

Cassandra can only enforce a sort order *within* a partition key.  For example, this means that you can select where rows with a certain date/times value in their first [clustering column](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/share/glossary/gloss_clustering_column.html), given a certain, specific value for the [partition key](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/share/glossary/gloss_partition_key.html).

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.timestamptest (
    userid text,
    activetime timestamp,
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, activetime)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (activetime ASC)

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm timestamptest 
                             WHERE userid='a' AND activetime > '2015-09-25';                
 userid | activetime               | value
--------+--------------------------+---------
      a | 2015-09-25 06:33:33-0500 |  value1
      a | 2015-09-25 06:34:33-0500 |  value2
      a | 2015-10-22 09:26:00-0500 |  value3

(3 rows)
```

Basically, you need to further partition your table in a way that makes sense for your application and query requirements.

This tends to be a confusing issue for many Cassandra dev, so I have included a link to an article that I wrote for DataStax earlier this year: [We Shall Have Order!](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/)

Comment: Thats good example. I got it now. So partition key is needed in condition, in addition to timestamp.

Comment: This will throw this error: message="Only EQ and IN relation are supported on the partition key (unless you use the token() function)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you cannot filter data with a column if it is not the *partition key* or a column that is indexed.

Their is an exception for clustering columns using the key words *allow filtering*.

For more details refer to [Datastax documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html).

Comment: You can indexed your timestamp column, but in most of the cases it is not very performing

Comment: I understood now. Aron's answer explained all well.